# User input in bubble sort

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm trying to write a code to let user write his own numbers and decide whether he wants them to be sorted in ascending or descending order, and order them with bubble sort. This is what I could write so far (aka the obvious entrance);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int n, a, number;
  printf("Enter your numbers. Write -1 to stop. \n");
  do {
    scanf("%d", &a);
  } while(a != -1);
  printf("Enter 1 if you want them to be in ascending order. Enter 2 if you want  descending order\n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  if(a = 1)
    do {
      system("PAUSE");
      return 0;
    }
```

My problem is, I really don't know how to merge bubble sort to that. In all examples I could find had arrays which've been set before hand. I'm thinking I should start with a for structure but I've no idea.

EDIT:

I've came this far thanks to the helps, it kind of "works" until I write 1 or 2 then it crashes. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int myarray[100],index,a,b,swap,turn;
index=0;
printf("Enter your numbers. Write -1 to stop. \n");
do{
            scanf("%d", &myarray[index]);
            index++;
            }while(myarray[index-1] != -1);
printf("Enter 1 if you want them to be in ascending order. Enter 2 if you want   descending order\n");
scanf("%d",&b);
if(b == 1) {
   for(turn=1; turn <= myarray[100] -1; turn++)

   for(index = 0; index <=  myarray[100]; index++)
   {
   if (myarray[index] > myarray[index+1]){ 
    swap  = myarray[index];
    myarray[index]   = myarray[index+1];
    myarray[index+1] = swap; }
    }
}
else {
   for(turn=1; turn <= myarray[100] -1; turn++)

   for(index = 0; index <=  myarray[100]; index++)
   {
   if (myarray[index] < myarray[index+1]){ 
    swap  = myarray[index];
    myarray[index]   = myarray[index+1];
    myarray[index+1] = swap; }
    }
}   
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: access to `myarray[100]` is Array out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum _order {
    Ascending=1, Descending
} order;

void swap(int *x, int *y){
    int wk;
    wk=*x;*x=*y;*y=wk;
}

int needSwap(int x, int y, order dir){
    if(dir == Ascending)
        return x > y;
    if(dir == Descending)
        return x < y;
    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(int *array, int top, int end, order dir){
    int i, j, swaped;
    for(i = top; i < end; ++i){
        swaped = 0;
        for(j = top + 1; j <= end - i; ++j)
            if(needSwap(array[j-1], array[j], dir)){
                swap(&array[j-1], &array[j]);
                swaped = 1;
            }
        if(swaped == 0)break;
    }
}

int main(){
    int myarray[100], index, order;
    index=0;
    printf("Enter your numbers. Write -1 to stop. \n");
    do{
        scanf("%d", &myarray[index++]);
    }while(myarray[index-1] != -1 && index < 100);
    --index;//Correction to point to the final value
    printf("Enter 1 if you want them to be in ascending order.\n"
           "Enter 2 if you want descending order\n");
    scanf("%d",&order);
    bubbleSort(myarray, 0, index-1, order);
    {//result print
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<index;++i)
            printf("%d ", myarray[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user315052: The same thing I have is with the outer loop.

Comment: bubble sort is "comparing each pair of adjacent items and swapping them if they are in the wrong order".

Comment: @user315052 : I glad you get to understand.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I am happy the asker got a correct answer, regards

Comment: note: not inherently related to the presence or absence of the swap flag is whether or not to optimize.

Comment: I am happy the asker got a correct answer too :) thank you so much guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the input into a single variable `a`, which gets overwritten each time you read more input. You should store each input so that your program will be aware of all the input that was provided, not just the last input provided.

An array is a bunch of variables of the same type arranged contiguously, and accessed with a single name and an index.

```
int arr[10];
```

In this example `arr` makes up 10 consecutive `int`s. You access the first `int` in the array with `arr[0]`, and the last one with `arr[9]`. To get your input into the array, you can store `a` into the proper index of `arr`. You can maintain the proper index by counting how many numbers the user has input so far. The count would be used as the index into the input array. Do not allow the user to exceed the array boundary defined in the declaration, or you will be invoking undefined behavior when you try to store data beyond that last position associated with the array (when this happens, it is called a buffer overrun).

After you have read your input into the array, you can then pass the array into a bubble sort function.

Let's suppose you have an input routine like this:

```
#define MAX_ARR 10
int a;
int entered = 0;
int arr[MAX_ARR];
while (entered < MAX_ARR) {
    if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) break;
    if (a == -1) break;
    arr[entered] = a;
    ++entered;
}
if (entered == MAX_ARR) {
    printf("No more room in the array (max is %d)\n", MAX_ARR);
}
```

We have checked that `scanf` has returned the expected return value. We have checked the input against the stop value, and we have made sure the user cannot enter more data than the array can hold.

The number of elements entered into the array is `entered`. So, to iterate over the array, the loop would look something like this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < entered; ++i) {
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

A very simple version of the bubble sort is just to keep looping over the array until you don't have to do any more swaps. You would swap whenever two consecutive elements are not in the desired order. For the ascending case:

```
int j, swaps, unsorted = entered;
do {
    swaps = 0;
    for (j = 1; j < unsorted; ++j) {
        /* ... if arr[j-1] and arr[j] need to swap then:
                   swap them, and
                   increment swaps ... */
    }
} while (swaps > 0);
```

You know that the element in the last position of the array will be in its sorted position at the end of one complete pass through the bubbling loop, so the number of `unsorted` can be decreased after each complete pass.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that you'll need to store these numbers in some kind of data structure like an array or vector. A vector is a good choice because you don't know how many numbers the user will enter. Here's a sketch you could apply to your code:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  // ...
  std::vector<int> userInts;
  // ... get input 
  userInts.push_back(a); // add int to the end of the list

  bubbleSort(userInts);
  // ...
}
```

**EDIT:** I failed to realize this was tagged as C and not C++. Just swap out the `std::vector` call with some code to dynamically allocate an array in C (or your own vector implementation). Alternatively, if you know only *N* integers will be input, then declare `int userInts[N]`, loop over the input, insert it into the array, and sort.

**EDITx2:** See @user315052's answer below for doing this with a fixed length array as described above.

Comment: @user315052: Ah, thanks -- I missed that. It was a jumble of unformatted and incomplete code when I answered this, and I made a faulty assumption.

Answer (score 1):

For the first version have an array of fixed size say

```
int myarray[100];
//Accept the integers 

index=0;
do {
    scanf("%d", &myarray[index]);
    index++;
}    while(myarray[index-1]!= -1);
```

Now you have the array and the count of the total number of 
   elements - (index-1)

You can apply  your sorting algorithm over the array.

Comment: Okay this was really helpful, but I can't seem "-1" to stop the imput. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Chnage `a` to `myArray[index-1]`, since that's what you're inputting now.

Comment: @chris Thanks Chris..I have added that in the answer.

Comment: I nearly got it working, yet it crashes after the compiling. Latest code at the original post, any ideas?